# Does SonarQube MSBuild Runner work with Microsoft.Build API?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I'm programmatically able to call `MsBuild.SonarQube.Runner begin` (by making calls into referenced assemblies directly), `Microsoft.Build.BuildManager.Build` and `MsBuild.SonarQube.Runner end`. But, the issue is `Runner end` reports that **No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Possible causes: you specified an invalid build configuration or the custom MSBuild analysis targets were not imported.**

Is MsBuild.SonarQube.Runner tightly coupled with MSBuild.exe commandline tool? I'm not clear on how exactly the runner gets details of build events.

Is it even possible what I'm trying to achieve?

I must add that `runner begin` and build are succeeding. bin\Debug folder is populated with built binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build projects programmatically using the *MSBuild* API and have *SonarQube* analysis performed as part of the build. The *SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild* is not tightly coupled to the *MSBuild.exe* command line.

*ImportBefore* functionality is implemented in the standard Microsoft targets files. For example, have a look at *%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets* which contains the following line:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\*" Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore')"/>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\*" Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore')"/>
```

All these lines do is import any target files that exist in well-known locations. This mechanism can be used to automatically include targets into every project, without having to explicitly include the targets file in the project. This mechanism is independent of *MSBuild.exe*. However, it does matter which version of standard targets files you are using: the v4.0 standard target files don't include this mechanism, but the v12.0 and v14.0 versions do.

The simplest way to trigger a build programmatically is to use MSBuild v12.0 or v14.0 and rely on the standard *ImportBefore* behaviour.

Alternatively, you could do one of the following:

1. manually edit your project files to explicitly include the required *SonarQube* targets, or
2. programmatically import the required *SonarQube* targets using the *MSBuild* API before triggering the build (by adding an "Item" of type "Import" with the *include* parameter pointing to the location of the targets file to import). The *SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild* integration tests use this approach.

Comment: I've moved on using `Process.Start()` to invoke `msbuild.exe` but your suggestions seem to be valid. Accepting that as an answer even though I've not given it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild is an open source project, so you can see for yourself how everything works under the hood: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner

I don't think it is tighly coupled to the MSBuild.exe command line, however it does depend on the `ImportsBefore` mechanism of MSBuild, and only works for specific MSBuild versions (12 and 14 currently).

Your question is about the implementation of a solution to some problem, however you don't say what this initial problem is. This makes it difficult to give a good answer.

Comment: `ImportsBefore` is MSBuild.exe specific functionality and since SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild depends on it, indirectly scanner becomes specific to MSBuild. Which means I can't use `Microsoft.Build` API. I'm planning to invoke MSBuild.exe as an external process. Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

Since MSBuild Runner for SonarQube depends on `ImportsBefore` feature of MSBuild and because `Microsoft.Build` API has no comparable for `ImportsBefore`, at least as of now there is no way to use Sonar Runner for MSBuild in conjunction with the API. It has to be used along with `MsBuild.exe` by means of process invocation.